# java mockito Could not create type

Tags: java, mockito

#### Description of Problem

I face problem when, I try codes from some **mockito** tutorial. Below, please see necessary codes and errors, including **pom.xml** and **stack trace**.

---

**My pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </parent>
    
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        </properties>
    
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.4</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.25.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-maven-plugin -->
            <!--<dependency>-->
                <!--<groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>-->
                <!--<artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
                <!--<version>3.6.2</version>-->
            <!--</dependency>-->
    
        </dependencies>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

#### My test:

```
    import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
    import com.google.common.io.Resources;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.mockito.Mock;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
    import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
    import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
    
    public class ParserTest {
    
        @Test
        public void update() throws IOException {
            Iterator i = mock(Iterator.class);
            when(i.next()).thenReturn("Hello").thenReturn("World");
            String result = i.next()+" "+i.next();
            assertEquals("Hello World", result);
        }
    }
```

---

#### My Stack Trace:

Stack trace is as follows:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 

Mockito cannot mock this class: interface java.util.Iterator.

Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes.
If you're not sure why you're getting this error, please report to the mailing list.


Java               : 1.8
JVM vendor name    : Oracle Corporation
JVM vendor version : 25.162-b12
JVM name           : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
JVM version        : 1.8.0_162-b12
JVM info           : mixed mode
OS name            : Windows 10
OS version         : 10.0
Underlying exception : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not create type
```

---

#### My Questions:

- Any idea what can be reason for this behavior?
- How do I solve this problem?

Comment: why are you mocking `Iterator`?

Comment: Because it was in tutorial and probably should work. I face problem to mock my class. So to be sure whether the problem with my class or with mockito I decide to try example from some tutorial.

Answer (score -2):

The problem you have is easy to solve, if you obey [Mockito's basic mocking principles](https://site.mockito.org/):

- **Do not mock types you don’t own**
- **Don’t mock value objects**
- Don’t mock everything
- Show love with your tests!

Please be sure to read also the detailed explanations, why you should not [mock type[s] you don't own](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/How-to-write-good-tests#dont-mock-type-you-dont-own).

Teaser: Escpescially for collections or collection-related classes in the JVM it is not just enough to mock one method like you did with `next()`, a consistent mocking of `hasNext()` has also to be done to prevent bad awakenings. :-)

So your test shrinks together to something like:

```
@Test
public void update() {
    Iterator i = List.of("Hello", "World").iterator();
    String result = i.next() + " " + i.next();
    assertEquals("Hello World", result);
}
```

If you read further in the [detailed docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html), Section *"1. Let's verify some behaviour!"* says:

> The following **examples mock a List, because most people are familiar with the interface** (such as the add(), get(), clear() methods). **In reality, please don't mock the List class. Use a real instance instead.**"

Comment: Dear mle, the question was "what is reason that example from tutorial not working for me". Not "should I use mockito to mock iterator?". I already tried to mock a lot of my own classes and always get same result. You response does not solve any problem!!!

Comment: And in mockito official site given example of moking List. 
List mockedList = mock(List.class);


https://site.mockito.org/

Comment: No please do not stick to the first example on the first page of Mockito! **Please read further** Consider the warning in the [detailed docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html), Section "1. Let's verify some behaviour!" says: **"The following examples mock a List, because most people are familiar with the interface (such as the add(), get(), clear() methods).
In reality, please don't mock the List class. Use a real instance instead. "**

Comment: See also my updated answer, the same is valid for `Iterator`. If you still want to mock the `Iterator`, check your `Mockito` version. With `2.23.x` the example in your question is working out-of-the box for me.